# Render Time Estimation using Blender Benchmark Score

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I want to estimate the time it takes for an image to render based on the Blender benchmark score. Suppose that I have a scene of similar complexity and render settings as the benchmark scenes.

According to the official website (https://opendata.blender.org/about/):

> The Blender benchmark Score refers to the hardware's ability to
> process samples during Cycles rendering. In particular it's the amount
> of samples per minute that a CPU or GPU can compute. The higher this
> number, the better.

Using this definition can I deduce that if I want to render my scene with 64 samples in HD quality, I could render 60 images per minute assuming a benchmark score of 3840 (about the same as the NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070), as this seems quite much? *(Clarification in the EDIT)*

PS: I know that a lot of assumptions go into that estimate especially that the scenes are of exactly the same complexity, but for the sake of this question it should be fine.

**EDIT:**
Of course, in this question, unrealistic assumptions are made. What might not be apparent in the initial question is that I am really interested in: Assuming a system with a *tested* score of 1000 and one with 2000, can I deduce that the latter will render the same scene with the same render settings approximately twice as fast?

Comment: At the end of the day, each scene, each hardware and each system are different. The big assumption in your estimation is ignoring those factors.

Comment: Obviously, the assumptions are unrealistic, however, what I am interested in given **ideal** conditions can the Blender benchmark score be reasonably interpreted as I have. Please also refer to the edit.